# Android - Get the Mask image X,Y coordinates with in overlay after zooming,Rotation,Moving

Tags: android, image-processing, android-canvas, masking

> I have an overlay with one mask-able transparent area with the
>   x,y,width,height prams.  i am taking one image from gallery and
>   placing that selected image at the Given x,y coordinates. This placing
>   is done in frame layout. Now i am able to rotate, zoom, move with in
>   that mask area. after i fitted into that mask are i want to get the
>   current x,y coordinates of the image with in the mask so that for
>   combining i am combining the image using canvas based on the x,y
>   position.presently i am taking the values using event.getx(), event.gety() in on touch . 
>   if i draw using those positions mask image is not drawing at the correct
>   position after i zooming or moving
>
> This is my code. Please help me if anyone have the idea.

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);

```
    mSelectedVersion = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
            CROP_VERSION_SELECTED_KEY, -1);
    Object overLayPath = getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("overLayPath") ? getIntent()
            .getExtras().get("overLayPath") : null;
    className = getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("class") ? (String) getIntent()
            .getExtras().get("class") : null;
    pageCount = (int) (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("pageCount") ? getIntent()
            .getExtras().getInt("pageCount") : 0);
    File file = new File(overLayPath.toString());

    String imgFile = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("bitmap");
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mScreenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    mScreenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    if (photoImg != null) {
        photoImg.recycle();
        photoImg = null;
    }
    if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("Fb_List")) {
        if (imgFile != null && !imgFile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            File imageFile = new File(imgFile);
            photoImg = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        if (imgFile != null && !imgFile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Uri selectedImageURI = Uri.parse(imgFile);
            InputStream is;
            try {
                is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageURI);
                if (photoImg != null) {
                    photoImg.recycle();
                    photoImg = null;
                }
                photoImg = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(is,
                        (int) (320 * metrics.density),
                        (int) (416 * metrics.density));
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cp_img);
    photoImg = createMaskImage(photoImg, mImg);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.transparentoverlay);
    } else {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(overLayPath.toString(), options);
    }
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImg.getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null && drawable.getBitmap() != null) {
        drawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        mImg.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
    mTemplateImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cp_face_template);
    mTemplateImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImg.setOnTouchListener(this);
    if (mScreenWidth > 600 && mScreenHeight > 1024) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                (int) (320 * metrics.density),
                (int) (416 * metrics.density), true);
        mTemplateImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else if (mScreenWidth > 460 && mScreenHeight > 720) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                (int) (320 * metrics.density),
                (int) (416 * metrics.density), true);
        mTemplateImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    mImg.setImageBitmap(photoImg);
    mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImg.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);

    // Setup Gesture Detectors
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(),
            new ScaleListener());
    mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(),
            new RotateListener());
    mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(MaskCropActivity.this,
            new MoveListener());

}

private Bitmap createMaskImage(Bitmap photoImg2, ImageView maskView) {
    if (photoImg2 != null) {
        String template = Common.getPrefrenceValue(
                Constants.TEMPLATE_OBJECT, MaskCropActivity.this);
        JSONObject templateObject = null;
        if (template != null && !template.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            try {
                templateObject = new JSONObject(template);
                JSONArray pageDetails = templateObject
                        .getJSONArray("pageDetails");
                JSONObject pageObject = pageDetails
                        .getJSONObject(pageCount - 1);
                JSONArray maskImages;
                maskImages = pageObject.getJSONArray("maskImages");
                if (maskImages != null && maskImages.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject maskObject = maskImages.getJSONObject(0);
                    String coOrdinates = maskObject.has("coOrdinates") ? maskObject
                            .getString("coOrdinates") : "";
                    if (coOrdinates.contains(",")
                            && coOrdinates.split(",").length == 4) {
                        int x = Integer.parseInt(coOrdinates.split(",")[0]);
                        int y = Integer.parseInt(coOrdinates.split(",")[1]);
                        maskX = x;
                        maskY = y;
                        int width = Integer
                                .parseInt(coOrdinates.split(",")[2]);
                        int height = Integer.parseInt(coOrdinates
                                .split(",")[3]);
                        if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
                            if (((photoImg2.getWidth() - (int) (width * metrics.density)) / 2)
                                    + (int) (width * metrics.density) > photoImg2
                                        .getWidth()
                                    || (50 + (int) (height * metrics.density)) > photoImg2
                                            .getHeight()) {
                                Log.i(TAG,
                                        "image size is less than required");
                                photoImg2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                        photoImg2,
                                        (int) (width * metrics.density),
                                        (int) (height * metrics.density),
                                        true);
                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG,
                                        "image size is more than required");
                                photoImg2 = Bitmap
                                        .createBitmap(
                                                photoImg2,
                                                (photoImg2.getWidth() - (int) (width * metrics.density)) / 2,
                                                50,
                                                (int) (width * metrics.density),
                                                (int) (height * metrics.density));
                            }
                        }
                        MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) maskView
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        mlp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);// all in pixels
                        maskView.setLayoutParams(mlp);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return photoImg2;
    }
    return photoImg2;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
        InputStream inputStream, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    byte[] byteArr = new byte[0];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            if (len != 0) {
                if (count + len > byteArr.length) {
                    byte[] newbuf = new byte[(count + len) * 2];
                    System.arraycopy(byteArr, 0, newbuf, 0, count);
                    byteArr = newbuf;
                }

                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, byteArr, count, len);
                count += len;
            }
        }

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        int[] pids = { android.os.Process.myPid() };
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}

public void onCropImageButton(View v) {
    // Create progress dialog and display it.
    try {

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cropping Image\nPlease Wait.....");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Setting values so that we can retrive the image from
    // ImageView multiple times.
    mImg.buildDrawingCache(true);
    mImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mTemplateImg.buildDrawingCache(true);
    mTemplateImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // Create new thread to crop.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mSelectedVersion == VERSION_1) {
                croppedImg = cropImage(photoImg, bitmap);
                Common common = new Common();
                if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("Fb_List")) {
                    storeImage(croppedImg, "overlay" + pageCount + ".png");
                } else {
                    Common.storeCropImage(croppedImg, "overlay1.png",
                            MaskCropActivity.this);
                    photoImg.recycle();
                }

            } /*
             * else { croppedImg = ImageProcess.cropImageVer2(
             * mImg.getDrawingCache(true),
             * mTemplateImg.getDrawingCache(true), 320, 440); }
             */
            // }
            try {

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            mImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            mTemplateImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        }
    }).start();
}

private boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData, String filename) {
    String iconsStoragePath = Common.SDCARD_PATH
            + Common.UNZIPPED_PATH
            + Common.getPrefrenceValue(Constants.ZIPFILE_NAME,
                    MaskCropActivity.this) + "/custom";
    File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);
    sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();
    try {
        String filePath = sdIconStorageDir.toString() + "/" + filename;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);
        System.out.println("imageData" + imageData);
        imageData.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MaskCropActivity.this,
                DesignPriviewEditing.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    float scaledImageCenterX = (mImageWidth * mScaleFactor) / 2;
    float scaledImageCenterY = (mImageHeight * mScaleFactor) / 2;

    mMatrix.reset();
    mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mMatrix.postRotate(mRotationDegrees, scaledImageCenterX,
            scaledImageCenterY);
    mMatrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaledImageCenterX, mFocusY
            - scaledImageCenterY);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    mMatrix.getValues(values);
    relativeX = (int) event.getX();
    relativeY = (int) event.getY();
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        return true;
    }
}

private class RotateListener extends
        RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
        mRotationDegrees -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();

        return true;
    }
}

private class MoveListener extends
        MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
        PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
        mFocusX += d.x;
        mFocusY += d.y;
        System.out.println("ON MOVE LISTSNER" + mFocusX + "MFOCUS Y"
                + mFocusY);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MaskCropActivity.this,
            CropImagesActivity.class);
    System.out
            .println("pageCount in mASK CROP ON BACK PRESSED" + pageCount);
    intent.putExtra("pageCount", pageCount);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap img, Bitmap templateImage) {

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (320 * metrics.density),
            (int) (416 * metrics.density), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas combineImg = new Canvas(bm);
    combineImg.drawBitmap(img, relativeX, relativeY, null);
    combineImg.drawBitmap(templateImage, 0, 0, null);
    return bm;
}
```